Python code to retrieve system info in format
I have to make a python script for a course I’m doing. It has to retrieve the following:

Computer Name
IP-address, MAC-address, Active ports
Processor Model Operation
System time
Internet connection speed

And print to a csv with the following formats:
PF1VKNRQ, 192.168.1.2, 54-05-DB-3B-71-31, i7, Windows 10, 6//10/2023 8:00:01, 3Mb/s, 21;25;443;1234 

Code I have so far is:
import csv
import os
import platform
import psutil
import socket
import struct 
import datetime

def get_system_info():
    system_info = {}

    system_info['Computer_Name'] = platform.node()
    system_info['IP_Address'] = 
    system_info['MAC_Address'] = 
    system_info['Processor_Model'] = 
    system_info['OS'] = platform.system() + platform.version([release])
    system_info[ 'Sys_Time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    system_info['Net_Con_Spd'] = 
    system_info['Active_Ports'] = 
    print(system_info)

get_system_info()

Can anyone help me find out how to fill in the other details to meet the reporting requirements?

I had solved a similar one for my project. Let me know if this works, first install the following libraries: pip install psutil speedtest-cli
import csv
import os
import platform
import psutil
import socket
import datetime
import subprocess
import uuid

def get_system_info():
    system_info = {}
    system_info["Computer_Name"] = platform.node()
    system_info["IP_Address"] = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    system_info["MAC_Address"] = ':'.join(['{:02x}'.format((uuid.getnode() >> elements) & 0xff) for elements in range(0,2*6,2)][::-1])
    system_info["Processor_Model"] = platform.processor()
    system_info["OS"] = platform.system() + " " + platform.version()
    system_info["Sys_Time"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['speedtest', '--simple'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        download_speed = None
        for line in result.stdout.splitlines():
            if 'Download' in line:
                download_speed = line.split()[1]
                break
        system_info["Net_Con_Spd"] = download_speed
    except Exception as e:
        system_info["Net_Con_Spd"] = "Error retrieving speed"
    active_ports = []
    for conn in psutil.net_connections(kind='inet'):
        active_ports.append(str(conn.laddr.port))
    system_info["Active_Ports"] = ';'.join(active_ports)
    return system_info

def write_to_csv(system_info):
    with open('system_info.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(system_info.keys())
        writer.writerow(system_info.values())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    system_info = get_system_info()
    write_to_csv(system_info)



MAC-address

uuid.getnode() from uuid part of standard library

Get the hardware address as a 48-bit positive integer. The first time
this runs, it may launch a separate program, which could be quite
slow. If all attempts to obtain the hardware address fail, we choose a
random 48-bit number with the multicast bit (least significant bit of
the first octet) set to 1 as recommended in RFC 4122. “Hardware
address” means the MAC address of a network interface.(...)

Keep in mind it does attempt to return said address, but is not guaranteed to do so. It does return integer, if you need to have hexadecimal address then use %X format string, that is
import uuid
mac = "%X" % uuid.getnode()
print(mac)

